# page not load when using httphandler

Tags: asp.net, redirect, httphandler

i use `HttpHandler`  for redirect old php page to new aspx page.
but when run project not load any page.

httpHandler:

```
public class Redirect:IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string url = context.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        if (url.Contains(".php"))
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Location", "../../fa/About.aspx");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
 <add name="Redirect" verb="*" path="*" type="ParsianTechnology.Utility.Redirect" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do this change:

```
<add name="Redirect" verb="*" path="*" type="ParsianTechnology.Utility.Redirect" />
```

to

```
<add name="Redirect" verb="*" path="*.php" type="ParsianTechnology.Utility.Redirect" />
```

It should solve your problem.